# Is it possible to run a stackR like arcade game from raspberry pi 3?

Tags: retropie, games

I was wondering if it is possible to create a STACK'R clone (the arcade game) and load it to raspberry pi 3 for my new arcade cabinet I'm creating.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is! You can use python with [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news).

You will have access to your arcade controls on your GPIOS through the `RPi.GPIO` library in python as well.

They have great tutorials and examples on their website.

However, if you want to use RetroPi than you just need to get the original rom and load it into the appropriate emulator.